# How to select element after it was added to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my HTML I have buttons list and text input field. Input field is to add extra buttons to my buttons list.

On jQuery I have eventListener when one of these buttons with .choices is clicked console log its value.

It works fine without any errors.  But when I add extra button to my list with same class (.choices) new button appears but it doesn't respond to my click.

Any suggestions?

```
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="button0" class="choices">Running</button>
  <button id="button1" class="choices">Yoga</button>
  <button id="button2" class="choices">Karate</button> 
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#add-button").click(function(){
  var inputValue = $("#add-input").val();
  var generatedId = "button" + healthyChoices.length;
  healthyChoices.push(inputValue);
  $("<button>").attr("id", generatedId).appendTo(".buttons");
  $("#" + generatedId).attr("value", inputValue);
  $("#" + generatedId).attr("class", "choices");
  $("#" + generatedId).text(inputValue);
  $("#add-input").val("");
});


$(".choices").click(function(){
  var selectedGroup = $(this).val();
  console.log(selectedGroup);
});
```

Comment: `$(".buttons").on('click', '.choices', function() {`

Comment: The comment @dfsq posted is how I'd do it, but I'd suggest further that they make it an answer with an explanation as to why that binds the event differently than what the OP posted. for points.  =)

Comment: If you do this: `newbutton = $("<button>")`, you can do `newbutton.attr("value", inputValue)`, etc without having to generate IDs, since you don't seem to be using them.,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: For performance reasons, I would advise you to avoid `$("#" + generatedId).method()` calls repeatedly like you are doing.  `var $newButton = $('<button>');`, alter the button, then append it.  Don't repeat unnecessary lookups.

Comment: Something such as: https://jsfiddle.net/63dbt0ye/

Answer (score 0):

The .click method does not handle elements dynamically added to the DOM. You should be using the .on method (as indicated by dfsq's comment).

See this SO post: [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)